# regeneratorRuntime is not defined in TypeScript run in web

Tags: typescript, vue.js, parceljs

I play a demo with Vue.js + TypeScript + Parcel, and try `async/await` in **index.ts** .

**index.html**

```
<html>
...
<body>
  <script src="index.ts"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**index.ts**

```
console.log('Not see me')
(async () => {
  console.log('Did not execute here too.')
})()
```

Execute `parcel index.html` and open the **http://localhost:1234/**. The console throw the error: **regeneratorRuntime is not defined**

```
index.a4a28941.js:110 Uncaught ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined
    at index.a4a28941.js:110
    at Object.parcelRequire.306 (index.ts:3)
    at newRequire (index.a4a28941.js:48)
    at parcelRequire.306 (index.a4a28941.js:80)
    at index.a4a28941.js:106
```

It seems the `async` syntax need the polyfill?

Here is my **tsconfig.json**:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "esnext",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["src/*"]
    },
    "lib": ["esnext", "esnext.array", "dom", "dom.iterable", "scripthost", "es2015.generator"]
  },
  "parcelTsPluginOptions": {
    // If true type-checking is disabled
    "transpileOnly": false
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.tsx", "src/**/*.vue", "tests/**/*.ts", "tests/**/*.tsx"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

Answer (score 11):

My solution  was to set the `target` to `"es5"` in the `tsconfig.json`file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5"
  }
}
```

However it seems like parcel is always using babel to transform javascript and that is causing some *clashes* with the typescript compiler (see here: https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/954 and here: https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/871). Some guys also solved this problem by requiring `babel-polifill` in their projects but this seems not to be the best option if you only want to use the typescript compiler and not having babel transforming anything.