# regeneratorRuntime is not defined - onnxruntime-web-bundler

Tags: onnx, onnxruntime

I tried to replicate the example found here: https://github.com/microsoft/onnxruntime-inference-examples/tree/main/js/quick-start_onnxruntime-web-bundler:

```
import * as React from 'react';

import ort from 'onnxruntime-web'
import regeneratorRuntime from 'regenerator-runtime'

function App_F() {


  // https://github.com/microsoft/onnxruntime-inference-examples/blob/main/js/quick-start_onnxruntime-web-bundler/main.js

  const onnxFunct = async () => {
    try {
      // create a new session and load the specific model

      // the model in this example contains a single MatMul node
      // it has 2 inputs: 'a'(float32, 3x4) and 'b'(float32, 4x3)
      // it has 1 output: 'c'(float32, 3x3)
      const session = await ort.InferenceSession.create('../../assets/onnx/model.onnx');

      //const dataA =  Float32Array.from([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12])
      //const dataB = Float32Array.from([10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110, 120])
      //const tensorA = new ort.Tensor('float32', dataA, [3, 4])
      //const tensorB = new ort.Tensor('float32', dataB, [4, 3])

      // prepare feeds. use model input names as keys
      //const feeds = { a: tensorA, b: tensorB }

      // feed inputs and run
      //const results = await session.run(feeds)

      // read from results
      //const dataC = results.c.data
      //console.log(`data of result rensor 'c': ${dataC}`)

    } catch (e) {
      console.log(`failed to inference ONNX model: ${e}. `)
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className='container'>
      <h1 className='heading'>
          F
      </h1>

    </div>
  );
}

export default App_F;
```

In `webpack.config.js` :

```
      new CopyPlugin({
        patterns: [
          {
            from: path.resolve(__dirname, "./node_modules/onnxruntime-web/dist/*.wasm"),
            to: path.resolve(__dirname, "[name][ext]")
          },
          {
            from: path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/assets/onnx"),
            to: path.resolve(__dirname, "./dist/assets/onnx")
          }
```

As suggested here: [regeneratorRuntime is not defined in TypeScript run in web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51262244/regeneratorruntime-is-not-defined-in-typescript-run-in-web)

I tried to convert `"target": "ESNext" ---> "target": "es5"`  in `tsconfig.json`:

`tsconfig.json` :

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": ["dom", "es2015", "ESNext"],
    "outDir": "dist",
    //"jsx": "react",
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "@sections/*": ["app/sections/*"],
      "@app/*": ["app/*"]
    },
    "strict": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noImplicitThis": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "allowJs": true
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "exclude": [
    "src/index.js",
    "dist",
  ]
}
```

But I get this error message : `regeneratorRuntime is not defined`

[image]

How to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue following the indications found here:[Uncaught ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61755999/uncaught-referenceerror-regeneratorruntime-is-not-defined-in-react)

I added in `package.json` :

```
"browserslist": [
  "last 2 Chrome versions"
]
```

Now I get another error : `failed to inference ONNX model: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'InferenceSession')` , but that's a different issue